# How to scroll a UITableView to the tableFooterView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView whose contents are dynamically changing, like a FIFO stack.  Cells are added to the bottom and removed from the top.

This works beautifully, and I can scroll to the indexPath so that the newest message always scrolls down to the bottom (Like a chat application).

Now.. I want to add a footer to that table section.  Instead of using

SrollToRowAtIndexPath

I would like to be able to scroll to the tableFooterView.

Any ideas how I can do that would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the best solution u used?>

Answer (score 28):

I am using this to scroll to the footer view of a tableView:

```
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:[self.tableView convertRect:self.tableView.tableFooterView.bounds fromView:self.tableView.tableFooterView] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Simple and easy to use anywhere!

Comment: +1! this is the correct answer, every other answer I tested did not work correctly under certain circumstances.

Comment: In theory that is good, in practice it can't be chained with table view updates - like inserts and deletes of rows while the table view is animating.   scrollToIndexPath works for that

Answer (score 27):

The best way to scroll a `UITableView` to the bottom of it's footerView is to simply set the content offset. You can calculate the bottom using the `contentSize` and the current `bounds`

Here is the way I do it.

```
CGPoint newContentOffset = CGPointMake(0, [self.instanceOfATableView contentSize].height -  self.instanceOfATableView.bounds.size.height);

[self.instanceOfATableView setContentOffset:newContentOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: I only managed to make it work when I added a delay after calling reloadTable: [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToBottom) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3]

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to iphone_developer here is what I did :

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Then while I'm adding rows, I'm calling this and my tableView's footer view keeps being visible

Swift Version:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.tblview.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: this will scroll to the toppest not bottom

Comment: Nope, [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1 is the last row, so scrolling to positionTop on this row will actually scroll the tableView to the bottom

Comment: @Beji this assumes you have only one section

Comment: It's interesting because I was doing that, but scrolling to the bottom, which was hiding the footer. Calling it with scroll position top works. thank you

Answer (score 13):

So many poor answers. :-)

The BEST way:

```
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:
     self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame animated:YES
];
```

Comment: This assumes that the `tableFooterView` will either always be a direct subview of `tableView` or that it sits at the origin of any intermediate views. While this might work now, there are no guarantees that the `tableView` subview hierarchy will stay the same in future iOS versions.

Comment: @Kumar KL , this is not working with custom footer and multiple footer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like:

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentSize.height) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, you can scroll to wherever you like using the UIScrollView method

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Just set the rect so that when it's visible the footer is visible, and you'll have your solution (you can use the footer's rect or something else, just so long as you get the right behavior all the time).

Answer (score 3):

My late answer is for developer, who need to show footer when the keyboard is shown.
The right solution is to consider contentInset property (which can be changed after keyboard is shown), so it's super easy:

```
- (void)scrollToFooter {
  UIEdgeInsets tableInsets = self.tableView.contentInset;
  CGFloat tableHeight = self.tableView.frame.size.height - tableInsets.bottom - tableInsets.top;
  CGFloat bottom = CGRectGetMaxY(self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame);
  CGFloat offset = bottom - tableHeight;
  if(offset > 0.f) {
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,  offset) animated:YES];
  }
}
```

I must notice, that in my case tableView was added to my own ViewController and one of cells have UITextField which become first responder. To move show footer when keyboard is shown you need to register keyboard did shown notification and (on iOS7) perform this method in the end of current run loop, coz in this case iOS7 automatically perform scrollToRowAtIndexPath after our method and footer will not be shown.

```
-(void)registerKeyboardNotification {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardDidShown:)
                                               name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShown:(id)notification {
  //move to the end of run loop
  [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToFooter) withObject:nil afterDelay:.0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use UITableViewScrollPositionTop on the LAST ROW in the LAST SECTION.  This works very well for me...

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:LAST_ROW inSection:LAST_SECTION] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Make sure your Table Footer View is well spaced out at the bottom and it should sit nicely animated inside the view...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

This good work for me!

```
CGRect footerBounds = [addCommentContainer bounds];
CGRect footerRectInTable = [tableview convertRect:footerBounds fromView:addCommentContainer];
[tableview scrollRectToVisible:footerRectInTable animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Swift 4

```
func addRow() {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: array.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.scrollToBottom()
    }
}

func scrollToBottom() {
    let footerBounds = tableView.tableFooterView?.bounds
    let footerRectInTable = tableView.convert(footerBounds!, from: tableView.tableFooterView!)
    tableView.scrollRectToVisible(footerRectInTable, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: i was checking this code, why need yo use DispatchQueue.main.async {}?

Answer (score 0):

Great idea, was looking for this myself :) Here's sample code, which would do the trick:

```
[tableView reloadData];
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:index
    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

You MUST have at least one cell in your tableView footer, the problem is that it's going to visible. Didn't have time to test, but I'd guess you could make it really small?

Additionally you must implement correct stuff inside **numberOfSectionsInTableView** (at least one for table and one for footer), **numberOfRowsInSection** (at least one for footer, your last section), **viewForHeaderInSection** (nil except for your cell), **heightForHeaderInSection** (maybe if you set this as zero), **cellForRowAtIndexPath** (add special case for your cell in footer)...

That should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
- (void)scrollToBottom{
   [self.myTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count] -1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This work to me:

```
- (void)tableViewScrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    if (numberOfRows) {
        if (self.tableView.tableFooterView) {
            [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:
             self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame animated:YES
             ];
        } else {
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:
             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:numberOfRows-1 inSection:0]
                                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                          animated:animated
             ];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I haven't tried, but what happens when you scroll to the last row+1?

Another idea would be to always add a dummy entry at the end and make it have a different look so it's seen as a footer.  Then you can always scroll to that.

Comment: You get an out of range error :( I should have mentioned that I tried that one already in the original post.